# How to insert new line character in Gtalk status message?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

How can I insert in lines in status message in gtalk ?

Is it allowed or not?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it allowed or not?

<s>It is allowed. Insert new lines by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd></s>

The Gtalk client doesn't have support for multiple lines in status message. The Gtalk web client within Gmail doesn't have such problems.

Comment: Not in status message sir, :(

Comment: @infant programmer Works fine http://imgur.com/FLjrx

Comment: but if I hit enter in status message bar, It accepts as enter .. sorry .. but this is what is happening :(

Comment: Possibly you have got confused between status message window and chat window, status message window is one "where busy/available/idle or a custom message is displayed" I know that shift+enter works for chat .. and I know many other tricks to .. except that **how to insert a new line in *status message*..**

Comment: @infant http://imgur.com/D8QCY if you can show me *which* status message you're talking about I can tell you for sure

Comment: if you go to Gtalk window, below your name (and pic) there will be a drop down list .. that is meant for setting ur status *available/busy/idle* etc .. in the same menu you can find custom message, while editing the custom message, you can't insert a new line, and make it look more attractive, I guess they have designed it intentionally for simplicity,

Comment: didn't work for me.